# What does "le" mean here?

Tags: pronombres

Please look at this sentence:

> ¿Pero hacen algo los críos, no?
>
> ¿Las marmotas ? no.
>
> No, **es la marmota que le sale**. Es la marmota y ...
>
> Es como si le saliera un grano al mar , un grano negro, una mota en el mar , marmota.
>
> También dícese del mar del, ¿Humorista castro manchego? mar-mota

What does "le sale" mean here? Who is "le"?
How can we rewrite the sentence if we don't use "le"? (That is, how to replace the pronoun.)

Comment: The meaning is a little vague, can you add some more context?

Comment: Looks like a conversation. Perhaps you could post the whole thing.

Comment: @leonboy y César: yes, it is from a conversation. I've editted my question again.

Comment: it does not yet makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

This dialog seems quite senseless. It seems to be taken from a humorous show or dialog (because I think that the "Humorista castro manchego" is José Mota, the famous Spanish comedian, and for that reason he says "mar-mota" -sea of José Mota). Many of these shows uses a lot of sentences intentionally ambiguous and many times use grammatically incorrect sentences just for fun.

Anyway, I think "le sale" is a use of the verb with an indirect object: so that this "le" would mean "**to him**". It's the same as saying:

> le salen a él.

as "él" is a pronoun when you say "a él" you have to add before the verb the pronoun "le". Sometimes "a él" is ommited because it's understood by the context, but you can't ommit "le"

> le salen a él = le salen

As for example you can say:

> Me salieron granos - I broke out in spots;

or

> Me salieron granos a mi.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes the conversation is extracted from the radio and they are making jokes for "marmota". Actually I did not understand what they were talking about.

Comment: if "le sale" is a reflexive verb, isn't it should be "se sale"? Why we use "le"?

Comment: @Cadenza yeah you're right it's an indirect object because it's not referring to the subject of the sentence. I've updated the answer.